# Conditional Distribution of Bivariate Normals

Tags: proof-verification, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, bivariate-distributions

I found a very weird formula for the conditional distribution of bivariate normals in a paper that I am reading. All of the results in the paper rely on it and I think it is incorrect.

---

Let

$$ y\equiv\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \sim N\left( \begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 \\ \mu_2 \end{bmatrix} , \Omega_y\right), \qquad \text{and} \qquad x\equiv\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \sim N\left( \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} , \Omega_x\right).$$

The paper writes that it follows that

$$ y | x \sim N\left( \left(\Omega_x^{-1}+\Omega_y^{-1}\right)^{-1}\left(\Omega_y^{-1}\mu+ \Omega_x^{-1}x\right) , \left(\Omega_x^{-1}+\Omega_y^{-1}\right)^{-1}\right), $$

where $\mu\equiv[\mu_1,\mu_2]'$.

---

This looks completely wrong to me. The covariance matrix is

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{Var}(x) & \operatorname{Cov}(x,y) \\ \operatorname{Cov}(y,x) & \operatorname{Var}(y) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Omega_x +\Omega_y& \Omega_y \\ \Omega_y & \Omega_y \end{bmatrix}$$

and, so, the conditional distribution should be

$$ y | x \sim N\left(\mu + \Omega_y\left(\Omega_x + \Omega_y\right)^{-1}\left(x-\mu\right)  , \Omega_y -\Omega_y\left(\Omega_x + \Omega_y\right)^{-1}\Omega_y \right). $$

I haven't been able to reconcile these two formulas. Can anyone verify that the formula in the paper is indeed incorrect or let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The conditional variance you suggest, namely, $$\Omega_y + \Omega_y\left(\Omega_x + \Omega_y\right)^{-1}\Omega_y$$ is incorrect and should read $$\Omega_y - \Omega_y\left(\Omega_x + \Omega_y\right)^{-1}\Omega_y$$ It is then a simple matter to show that this matrix coincides with the matrix $$\left(\Omega_x^{-1}+\Omega_y^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$ in the paper.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I corrected the typo, but I still don't see how it is a simple matter to obtain their result from there. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: To be shown: $$B-B(A+B)^{-1}B=(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}$$ This is equivalent to $C=I$, where $$C=(B-B(A+B)^{-1}B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})$$ But $$C=BA^{-1}+I-B(A+B)^{-1}BA^{-1}-B(A+B)^{-1}$$ hence it suffices to show that $$BA^{-1}-B(A+B)^{-1}BA^{-1}-B(A+B)^{-1}=0$$ or that $$A^{-1}-(A+B)^{-1}BA^{-1}-(A+B)^{-1}=0$$ or that $$(A+B)A^{-1}-BA^{-1}=I$$ which you can probably prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following identities, suppose $\mathbf{y}$ has a marginal Gaussian distribution (note that it comes out a little cleaner in terms of the precision $\Lambda = \Sigma^{-1}$), 
$$
p(\mathbf{y}) = \mathcal{N}\left( \textbf{y} | \mathbf{\mu},\Lambda^{-1}\right)
$$
and that conditional on some linear transformation of $\mathbf{y}$ we have
$$
p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{y}) = \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{x} |\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{b , \mathbf{L}^{-1}} \right),
$$
then the conditional distribution of $\textbf{y}$ given $\textbf{x}$ is 
$$
p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}) = \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{\Sigma}\left(\mathbf{A}^T L(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b})+\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{\mu} \right), \mathbf{\Sigma} \right)
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma} = \left(\mathbf{\Lambda} + \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{L} \mathbf{A}  \right)^{-1}.
$$
Applying this with $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}$, $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1} = \Omega_y$, and $\mathbf{L}^{-1} = \Omega_x$ then you get the result stated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you mind giving me a reference where I can find these identities? I have searched quite a bit and haven't found it yet.

Comment: Sure Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" has it, will have a quick search for an online reference, otherwise you can derive the result by applying Baye's theorem

Comment: Here are a set of slides derived from Bishop which indicate the Bayes' approach http://www.utstat.utoronto.ca/~radford/sta414.S11/week4a.pdf